# How do I share a CUPS printer with a Windows VirtualBox guest?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, cups

I'm currently using Ubuntu but I have printing set up with CUPS. Is it possible to share a CUPS printer with a VirtualBox Windows guest? Or, namely Windows 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## YES

Sharing a printer from a Linux/CUPS host to a Windows Virtual Machine is easy. I'll show you how to do this on Windows 2000 because it's probably the most old, and difficult (and, somewhat practical) configuration to get working.

1. Add a `Host Only Network`: `File` → `Preferences` → `Network` → `Host Only Networks` → `Add Host Only Network`. This will create your a network to the guest. The host will have the IP address of `192.168.56.1`.
2. Add a `Network Adapter` in the `Machine Settings` of VirtualBox. Right click the Virtual Machine → click `Settings` → click `Network` → Set `Attached to` on `Adapter 1` (or any adapter) to `Host Only Adapter`.
3. Go to the website [`http://localhost:631/`](http://localhost:631/).

   1. On the top tab click `Administration` → check both `Share printers connected to this system` and `Allow printing from the Internet` → click the `Change Settings` button.
   2. On the top tab click `Printers` → click the printer you want to share, and copy the url. For me, mine is `http://localhost:631/printers/Samsung-M262x-282x`. You want to replace `localhost` with `192.168.56.1`, and copy that.
4. Now we have two options. One of them is to track down the original driver, the other is to use the PostScript Definition file that Linux is using, and install the ability for Windows to use that. If the printer is a PostScript printer, that's a ton easier. We're going to assume it is.  A sane printer daemon should be able to read .ppd's (PostScript Printer Definitions), but Windows can't. In order to obtain that ability we need to install some third party software.

   1. Now you need to share `/etc/cups/ppd/`. Right click the Virtual Machine → click `Settings` → click `Shared Folders` → click `Add a Shared Folder` (icon on right). In the `Folder Path` put `/etc/cups/ppd/`. Click both `Automount` and `Read-only`.
   2. Now in the Virtual Machine, you want to install the [`Adobe Universal PostScript Windows Driver`](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=1500) I think this may come in versions of Windows newer than win2k. You can download this direct to the Virtual Machine, or you can save it to the host and share the directory you saved it to (just like we did above.)
   3. Run the file you just downloaded (`winsteng.exe`).

      1. Click `Next`.
      2. Click `ACCEPT` (the EULA screen)
      3. Click `It is connected to the network (Network Printer)` to add a Network Printer.
      4. Click `Next`
      5. Paste the address from above (in `3.2`).. Should looking something like `http://192.168.56.1/printers/<something>`.
      6. Click `Yes` to install the driver.
      7. Click `Browse` to find a *more* suitable driver. ;)
      8. Click `Network`.

         1. uncheck `Reconnect on Login`
         2. click `Browse` → expand `Virtual Box Shared Folders` → expand `\\Vboxsvr` → click `\\VBOXSVR\ppd` → click the `OK` button.
      9. Click `Drive` → click whatever drive you just added, defaults to `E:`.
      10. Click the printer on the left.
      11. Click the `OK` button.
      12. Make sure the new printer driver is selected (this should be the same screen from Step 5 above.
      13. Click `Next`.
      14. Choose to print the test page.
      15. Click `Install`
      16. You're done! I don't suggest you configure it unless you're special. Click a few Nexts and Finish.

*These instructions were written with an [Abandonware copy of Windows 2k Pro SP4](https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-nt-2000/final)*

Comment: A MS Publisher printer would replace all the long explanations of installing postprint functionality in windows.. as it functions the same way..